# Datatype Error in Import -export wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

may any one please help me on this.

i have a column in table which has data type datetime2, which is expected to
hold data like **(12/15/2015  12:12:00 PM)**.

but when i am importing data from flat file and configure the property of the column to **database time with precision** i got the below error

```
There was an error with input column "DTFETCH" (196) on input "Destination Input" (131). 
The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".

 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Kindly share your expertise... Thanks

Comment: What is the data value you tried to import?

Comment: @TabAlleman: values are like 12/15/2015  12:12:00 PM,           '12/15/2015  12:13:00 PM...etc. Thanks

Comment: Add a viewer to the connection going into the Destination Input and find out what value of DTFETCH is causing the error.   You are trying to pass some value that isn't a valid datetime2.

Comment: @TabAlleman: Thanks... i am looking into it...

Comment: @TabAlleman: i am using import-export wizard to load data from file to table. in property configuration i had choose DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 for the column. but not sure DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 in source and datetime2 in destination will work or not. appreciate your help